# Выделение памяти под элементы связного списка происходит медленнее, чем под вектор? C++

Tags: c++, память, vector, производительность, linked-list

Прочитал, что обращение к системе через new для выделения памяти - медленная операция. В связных списках память выделяется отдельно под каждый элемент. В векторе же память выделяется под внутренний массив, где элементы в памяти расположены последовательно, а выделение происходит только один раз (не берем в расчет возможное изменение вектора и списка). А зачит, что инициализация списка должно происходить медленнее, чем инициализация вектора. Верно ли это?

Comment: В Вашем высказывании есть одна ошибка - new не обращается на каждый чих к системе. А в целом, надо тестить на реальных примерах.

Comment: Если отводить память под все элементы вектора за раз, то это верное предположение

Comment: а ещё не стоит забывать, что создание списка это не только выделение памяти под каждый элемент, а ещё и установка пары указателей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае - да, в конкретных - надо мерять.

Например, сравнить время выполнения

```
    vector<int> v;
    ...
    vector<int> n {v.begin(),v.end() };
```

и

```
    list<int> n {v.begin(),v.end() };
```

См. https://ideone.com/w68bVP - в общем-то, как вы и предполагаете :)

P.S. Поскольку @avp высказал сомнения в том смысле, что скорость будет выше при выделении памяти вектору сразу - попробуем записывать элементы по одному.

С примерно тем же результатом - https://ideone.com/pihc47